# Regex for increasing/decreasing number pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I test for an increasing or decreasing number pattern in a string?
Assuming the string is just a number.

Ex:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(...) // something here
regexp.test("123456789") //true
regexp.test("121231234") //false
regexp.test("987654321") //true
regexp.test("5678901234") //true
```

The test would be for a cycle of digits really. 
How could this be achieved?

Comment: 135 is a valid match?

Comment: Why do you need regex?

Comment: Why do you need to use regex for this? Why not just parse the number and compare it using regular math expressions?

Comment: I'm using angular to match a pattern for validation

Comment: 13570123 is valid ?

Comment: What do you mean? I failed to see what Angular has to do with this.

Comment: @marvel308, skipping numbers would not be a match; but thanks

Comment: @sstyvane yes, I know I can do it with simple enough JS, but I wanted to hook into Angular's validation engine by providing a regex pattern for input validation.

Comment: are you only talking about single digit numbers, or is something as `[8,9,10,11,12,13].join("") -> "8910111213"` also valid?

Comment: yes, single digit numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mess of a regex is the best I can produce. It finds groups of ascending or descending numbers. You'd need to throw a starting and ending check on either end but, I didn't know what kind you want. For example you may want to have start line(^) and end line($) wrapped around this regex. It uses lookaheads which you may want to lookup if you are unfamiliar http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

```
(((?=01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90)\d)+|((?=
09|98|87|76|65|4|43|32|21|10)\d)+)\d
```

Comment: `(((?=01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90)\d)+|((?=09|98|87|76|65|54|43|32|21|10)\d)+)\d` removed the obsolete brackets but I'm still struggling to fully understand it. Nice job.

Comment: I've edited my answer with your improvement. I wanted to find a add comments with the regex. But, I got annoyed writing it because of long line lengths and formatting problems so I just threw it out there.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need to use regexp to do this, then this is simplest solution that comes to my mind:

```
/(^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$)|(^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$)/
```

`*` means "any number of".

Comment: what about 5678901234 ?

Comment: Oh, then simply add `|(^5678901234$)`. On a serious note, I really hope OP just did a mistake saying this should be valid.

Comment: it matches `11112` !

Comment: Very nice, but watch out for matching the empty string on this one. You could add `/(?=.)((^0*1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*$)|(^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$))/` to ensure you have at least a single character present.

Comment: This matches when numbers are skipped, e.g. `135`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you can achieve that with regex, but definitely can do that with `reduce`.

```js
const test = ["123456789", "121231234", "987654321", "5678901234"];

const results = test
  .map((item) => item.split(''))
  .map((item) => {
    let lastDigit = item[0];
    return item.slice(1).reduce((flag, digit) => {
      const ret = flag && digit > lastDigit;
      lastDigit = digit;
      return ret
    }, true)
  });

console.log(results);
```