# Finding a pattern that searches for numbers in descending order of an input string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Given the provided boilerplate:

```
def sorted():    
    return ""

line = stdin.readline()
re.search(sorted(), line)
```

I want to switch the return of `sorted` from `""` to some regular expression that  makes `re.search(sorted(), line)` match if the digits in the string are in descending order.

For example, `"7622"`, `"000"` and `"942"` should match but not `"354"`, `"456"`, `"hu221"`.

I am new to regex and I have only dealt with searching for initial characters in the input string and other very easy stuff and have not dealt with more complicated problems like this one.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking here--why do you need regex for this? Seems like `sorted("851")[::-1] == list("851")` is the most direct solution to what I _think_ you want....

Comment: Yes, that is how i would want to solve it but I am supposed to use regex. The code skeleton above was given

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you made a good faith attempt at coming up with a regex on your own? Keep in mind, regex is the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: I have tried to come up with a solution but I wouldn't know how to get the program to interpret the number characters in the string as numbers and then know that the sequence is decsending

Comment: I'm still learning so just to break down the expression ^(0(?!.*?[1-9]))*$ that you created. Parenthesis means we are looking in a group and the first number to search for is 0. Then since '.' just represents any character, '.*?' is not any character at all? How does that make sense, I am clearly miss interpreting  your expression but what am i missing?

Comment: Also, as an aside, `sorted` is a poor choice for a method name because it overwrites a builtin function in the standard library. The education system these days... sigh.

Comment: Actually, there's a better approach than lookaheads. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803860/regex-for-increasing-decreasing-number-pattern).

Comment: Yes, thanks ^9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1*0*$ is a solution to the problem if the only input string is a number string, thanks! You have been of great help and I learned a lot studying your code

Comment: BTW, if you found a solution that works for you, you can post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it. If you used code from the other link, you should reference it, though. If it's a duplicate, someone can vote to close it.